# Loop over a file and read values from two columns into variables

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I have a file (`data.dat`) which contains 3 columns. I want to read in two of them with the shell script and fill the contents into a template file.
The file looks like this:

```
12 180 2390
14 177 2210
16 173 2130
...
```

So far I can do that with one variable (which is column 2 in the data-file) as follows:

```
for a in `cat data.dat | gawk '{print $2}'`; do
 sed s/A/$a/ daily.template daily.template > daily.inp
done
```

Now I want to read in column 3 as well and give the according value (b) of the same line as column 2 to the same template. The template contains variables called "A" and "B".
I cannot do a nested for loop as I don't want to iterate each value of a over each value of b.

How can I achieve this?

**Addition:**

First of all thanks for all your help!

Yes, it might be more easy to understand if I give more information about the daily.template file. It is looking similiar to:

```
dens_column O3 300.00
dens_column h20 B
sza A
day_of_year 172
output sum
...
```

A and B should be replaced in every loop over the lines.
The first column in data.dat does not mean anything, it just displays the time of a measurement and this parameter is not needed in "daily.inp".
I just want one "daily.inp" for each line where A and B are replaced with the according value of column 2 and 3 in the according line.
So a daily.inp file like:

```
dens_column O3 300.00
dens_column h20 2390
sza 180
day_of_year 172
output sum
...
```

Then the next file separate:

```
dens_column O3 300.00
dens_column h20 2210
sza 177
day_of_year 172
output sum
...
```

And so on...

Comment: So `daily.template` contains the same number of lines as `data.dat`?  And each line in `daily.template` has variables `A` and `B`?  And each line in `data.dat` should be matched up with the same line in `daily.template`?  Are both files in the expected order?  Does the `12`, `14`, `16` have any meaning?  Does it also appear in `daily.template`?

Comment: Please provide a sample `daily.template` and the expected output.

Comment: The resulting file will contain only one line (the last you worked on). If that's not wanted, move the `>daily.inp` after the `done`.

Answer (score 8):

Then that should only be a matter of:

```
while read discard x y discard; do
  sed "s/A/$x/g;s/B/$y/g" < daily.template > "daily.$x-$y.inp"
done < data.dat
```

The `read` command will read one line at a time from `data.dat`, put the first field (fields being blank separated, and where backslash can be used to escape the field or line separator) in the variable `$discard`, the second in `$x`, the third in `$y` and the rest of the fields in `$discard`.

Comment: Thanks. If I try this I receive the error: Syntax error: "done" unexpected (expecting "do"). And where in this command do I define where to find (which column) A and B ?

Comment: @user46489, please make sure you copy it as-is, and make sure the pasted text has normal Unix-style line endings.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Unfortunately I still receive the same error. I was copying the code and replacing  A, B, data.dat with the according variables/file. I checked that there is no extra space somewhere. I don't know what else could be wrong...

Comment: @user46489, if it says it's expecting `do`, that's because you've not entered the `do` as in the text I wrote. One possible explanation is that you entered `do<Cr>` (`<Cr>` being the invisible carriage return characters sometimes added at the end of the line when working on Microsoft operating systems). Which is why I suggested you make sure you write the file in Unix format. When editing the file with `vim`, type `:set ff=unix`

Comment: thank you. Indeed I had a problem with the format as I am using Linux in a virtual box on my Windows computer. So now I solved the `do` problem. But, if I want to process following code: `while read discard sza dens_h2o discard; do 
  sed "s/SZA/$sza/g;s/DENS_H2O/$dens_h2o/g" < daily_SUR.template > daily_SUR.inp 
  echo $sza $dens_h2o
done < datenum_sza_dens_lowRes_test.dat` I got the error message:`:not foundy_loop.test.sh: 4: :No such file or directory` and then the correct echo of the variables...

Answer (score 0):

You can save the two columns in `gawk` printing `$2` and `$3`.  Then, extract those in separate variables `a1` and `a2` using `col`.  From there on, it is straightforward to `sed` the two template variables.

Comment: Thanks @unxnut! Could you give me the complete command as I am not using shell script usually, so I have already problems following your description! That would be very kind! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can use termsql for that job:

```
while read a b; do
   termsql -xwi daily.template "update tbl set COL2='$a' where COL1='h20'; update tbl set COL1='$b' where COL0='sza'" > daily$a$b.inp
done < <(termsql -wi data.dat "select COL1,COL2 from tbl")
```

Advantage: If you know SQL, you don't have to learn new syntax.

You can get termsql here:
https://gitorious.org/termsql